# Casting with 'as' - why doesn't this work?

Tags: c#, ado.net, casting, type-conversion

Maybe it's just too early in the morning and I'm being an idiot, but I'm a bit confused by this....

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("prc_FooBar", conn));
object obj = cmd.ExecuteScalar();

 // this is fine
decimal? d = (decimal?)(obj as double?);

// this doesn't compile
decimal? d = (obj as double?) as decimal?;
```

Why doesn't the last version compile?

Comment: what is the error that you get? Also the first line that is fine, does it execute without giving a runtime exception?

Comment: My compiler (4.0) disagrees with you on the second "this is fine"

Comment: yes sorry that was a mistake, i have edited

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `as` operator is not the same as a cast.  This blog explains:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2004/03/12/what-s-the-difference-between-cast-syntax-and-using-the-code-as-code-operator.aspx

It only "casts" between types in the same hierarchy, basically following the "is-a" idea.  A `decimal?` is not a `double?`, but the compiler can trick you into thinking it can be when you `(decimal?)myDouble;` because it is explicitly casting it for you with the loss of information.  The `as` operator does not do this for you and thus fails.

**Update:** you ask why there is a compiler error as opposed to a null result.  This is because the `as` operator can never conceivably get `double?` to `decimal?`.  Try:

```
string s = "";
MyClass f = s as MyClass;
```

Out of the box, this doesn't work because the compiler knows this.  It is better to get a compiler error because it can never work in it's current state.

Under normal usage, the `as` operator can be used to forward cast base types into derived types if the type is actually the type you think it is.  However, the type could be another derived type (this compiles):

```
MyBase b = new MyDerived1();
MyDerived2 d = b as MyDerived2();
```

Although the compiler technically *could* know this (in some situations), if it doesn't it responds with null if the cast fails.

I'm sure someone is about to come along and tell me how wrong I am :-)

Comment: but why is it an error, and not just resolved to `null`? (See my comments to Jon Hanna)

Answer (score 3):

From the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt%28v=vs.71%29.aspx):

> ... the **as** operator only performs reference conversions and boxing conversions.

Converting from `double?` to `decimal?` doesn't fit either of these categories, since there is no boxing going, and `double?` isn't a subtype or supertype of `decimal?`.

Comment: Since he uses decimal? as type, its actually a reference type: Nullable<decimal>.

Comment: @Aidiakapi: `Nullable<T>` is *not* a reference type, although the compiler allows nullables to mimic the behaviour of ref types in some ways. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx

Comment: @LukeH, thanks for correcting me, someone told me it was, who I assumed it was.

Comment: I was originally commenting on the scenario I thought it fell into, but you've since edited your answer so my comment makes no sense! :-)

Answer (score 1):

`var x = v as X` is equivalent to:

`var v = v is X ? (X)v : null;` but with only a single type-checking operation happening (`(X)v` on its own checks that v is, or can be cast to, X and throws an exception otherwise).

Your latter case is equivalent to:

```
double? tmp = obj is double? ? (double?)obj : null;
decimal? d = tmp is decimal? ? (decimal?)tmp : null;
```

It's known at compile-time that `tmp` is a `double?` (with either a value, or no value making it equivalent to `null`). The test of `tmp is decimal?` is therefore always false, and the operation fails at compile time.

Comment: this is a very clear explanation, thank you. This behaviour seems strange though....  you seem to be saying that the only reason `double? as decimal?` is a compile time error is because the compiler determines the result will always be null, yet i can happily write `null as decimal?` without an error.

Comment: `as` is intended to be used for casting, so someone trying to do an impossible cast has probably got a bug. The compiler has saved you, as it would be harder to find and fix if it just assigned null to d every time.